# Unable to update, screen freeze or no video signal

Tags: installation, 12.10, nvidia, freeze

I am no longer able to update Ubuntu!

The screen freezes when installing from fresh using a CD (even with `nomodeset` and other options set).

For my last install I used the alternate install for 12.04 LTS which allowed me to get to a root shell and install the `nvidia-current-updates` drivers and then reboot. However alternative installers does not seem to be available any more.

If I update the system from 12.04 (3.5.0-23-generic) with the update manager, the video signal is lost after reboot. This happens after GRUB even if `nomodeset` etc.

I can still SSH in but have not been able to get graphics working despite changing drivers and a whole lot of experimentation.

I have an old Dell PowerEdge T100, Intel architecture, and a new Eizo screen using Nvidia GT218 [NVS 300] video card.

Am I stuck on the 12.04 initial build forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Answering my own question if it can help anyone else.

**Problem 1**
screen freezes during ubuntu 13.04 install on system with nvidia graphics

**Solution 1** 
Unfortunately the alternate installer is no longer available but it is still possible to use a non-graphical install method. The method I used is called NetbootInstallFromInternet and it is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet.

**Problem 2**
The install will successfully finish and when I select ubuntu in the grub menu the screen turns completely black and after some time the video signal is lost and the screen is frozen.

**Solution 2**
Login again but select the recover menu, activate network, then open a root prompt and change the grub menu to by default go into text mode:

replace GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"

Now I could log on again into text mode and I started to try experiment with the nvidia drivers current and current updates, experimental, nomodeset and everythng else that has helped me in previous releases but none of that seem to work.

Then I removed all opendrivers and installed the nvidia proprietary drivers. I got an error message that the installprep or something did not work but hit continue anyway.  Then entered startx to fire up the graphical interface and it worked.

More details here: http://dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html (Step 4 is what worked for me)

Good luck!